# usage of 'Having to'

Tags: gerunds, present-participles

A sentence from a high school textbook :

'Originally, matches on Boxing Day were played against local rivals to avoid teams and their fans *having to* travel long distances after Christmas Day.'

What is the grammatical usage (or should I call it) of 'having' in this sentence?

Comment: "To avoid [the teams] having to..." means "so that they don't have to..."

Comment: There are [a lot of similar questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=have+to+obligation) about this use of "have to" to express obligation. See e.g. [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109008/how-to-use-having-to-verb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammatical function of *having* is gerund, or gerund participle, so it functions as a noun.

I prefer the possessive form for *teams* and *fans*, so as to be clear that the aim here is to avoid the travelling and not the teams and their fans.

> Originally, matches on Boxing Day were played against local rivals to avoid [the] **teams'** and their **fans'** having to travel long distances after Christmas Day.

I have also added the definite article as Kate has suggested.